How to bundle NodeJS Backend Application to Windows Executable (With Typescript Decorators)
I want to bundle a NodeJS Application (Express Server) that is also using Typescript Decorators (through GraphQL Modules) into a single executable. This executable should be "shipped" to Clients as a single executable for simplification.
First Test with esbuild & pkg --> Failed: as Decorators are not supported, without Decorators this is working quite well and I have a single .exe file at the end.
Second Test with Vite --> Quite close
vite.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { VitePluginNode } from 'vite-plugin-node';
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';
import graphqlLoader from 'vite-plugin-graphql-loader';

import { builtinModules } from 'node:module';

export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    // vite server configs, for details see [vite doc](https://vitejs.dev/config/#server-host)
    port: 3210,
    open: '/graphql'
  },
  resolve: {
    preserveSymlinks: true
  },
  plugins: [
    tsconfigPaths(),
    graphqlLoader(),
    ...VitePluginNode({
      adapter: 'express',
      appPath: './index.ts',
      exportName: 'viteNodeApp',
      initAppOnBoot: true,
      tsCompiler: 'swc',
      swcOptions: {
        minify: true,
        jsc: {
          target: 'esnext',
          parser: {
            syntax: 'typescript',
            decorators: true
          },
          transform: {
            legacyDecorator: true,
            decoratorMetadata: true
          }
        }
      }
    })
  ],
  build: {
    minify: true,
    target: 'node',
    ssr: './index.ts',
    outDir: 'dist',
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        inlineDynamicImports: true
      },
      preserveSymlinks: true,
      external: [...builtinModules, ...builtinModules.map((m) => `node:${m}`)]
    }
  },
  ssr: {
    external: [...builtinModules, ...builtinModules.map((m) => `node:${m}`)],
    noExternal: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? [/.*/] : undefined
  }
});

This is creating a single index.mjs file, that is still requiring node core modules in the imports. (Like f.e.: import require$$0$a, { Readable } from 'stream';)
I was not able to bundle this .mjs file with pkg (Command: pkg -C GZip -t latest-win -o bin/test.exe dist/index.mjs) into an exe. The following error is popping up:
Warning Failed to make bytecode latest-x64 for file C:\snapshot\test\src\services\test\dist\index.mjs
Maybe I'm currently totally on the wrong way and there is a much simpler way to achieve that. Please guide me.

Generally it's tsc+pkg

@EstusFlask And it will be all in one file? :O I don't have to ship node_modules or .js files? That would be a solution for me then.

Yes, that's how it's supposed to work. You don't need to bundle the app, it doesn't make a difference for pkg to wrap many .js files, which the output of tsc is, or only one. Whether it's it's feasible depends on third-party libs you use. Btw bun is an alternative, it's not production ready but if it works for you, it works
